# Get Data From Specific Column

Tags: c#, dataset

I have the below code to search by EmployeeID to find BirthDate but it doesn't seem to work and I'm unsure why, it says something about invalid arguments. Any ideas?

```
String birthDate = dsEmployees.Employees.FindByEmployeeID(ID).BirthDate.ToString();
```

Just says :

> 1 The best overloaded method match for 'Northwind.dsEmployees.EmployeesDataTable.FindByEmployeeID(int)' has some invalid arguments    C:\Users\Kimmy\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Northwind\Northwind\frmSignIn.cs   43  33  Northwind

Comment: You don't give the exact compiler error, and you tell us nothing about the types and methods that appear in the one line of code. Are we supposed to divine the answer?

Comment: Just says 1 The best overloaded method match for 'Northwind.dsEmployees.EmployeesDataTable.FindByEmployeeID(int)' has some invalid arguments C:\Users\Kimmy\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Northwind\Northwind\frmSignIn.cs 43 33 Northwind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
String birthDate = 
    dsEmployees.Employees.FindByEmployeeID(Convert.ToInt32(ID.ToString())).BirthDate.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realise that I have forgotten to convert it to an integer!

Answer (score 1):

Invalid Argument often means that you are passing a wrong parameter to a function. This probably means the variable ID is not ok :)

But you have provided less than enough information to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your FindByEmployeeID() function work but taking the value of a single cell in a dataset is usually done this way :

```
dataSet.Tables["tablename"].Rows["rowNumber"]["ColumnName"].toString();
```